# How to display multiple columns in categories when "Column with drilldown " shows the second layer

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts, drilldown

I have two categories as CAT 1 and CAT2 and those categories have Tokyo and  New York Columns. [image]

when I click the new york  column in CAT 1 I get this[image]

my question is why I cannot get multiple columns in categories when I drilldown to second layer? this is my jsfiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/aergunae/0vvv4eqo/1/
 and codes are below, thank you in advance

```
        series: [{      
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9,71]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [{y:49.9, drilldown:'ny 1'}, 71.5]

        }],
        drilldown:{
            series: [ 
            {name:'nyc1',
                id: 'ny 1',
                data: [{y:39.9, name:'name1'}, {y:31.5, name:'name2'}]

            }, {name:'nyc2',
                id: 'ny 1',
                data: [{y:39.9, name:'name1'}, {y:31.5, name:'name2'}]

            }]
          }
```

Comment: Drilldown from multiple series to multiple series is not supported in highcharts, but there are plans to add this. Right now you can develop workaround by adding and removing series using chart.addSeries(). Of course it may not work perfectly. You can use [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/7u1ta7zz/2/).